# What are the steps that I am missing or messing up on in order to get the matrix to reduced echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning

1)

original

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 6 \\
        2 & 8 & 4 & 22\\
        1 & 1 & 7 & 18\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
reduced echelon form
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 3.0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 1.0\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 2.0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Where I am stuck:

1) I did $-2R_1 + R_2$

2) I did $- R_1 - R_3 $

3) Reduce row $2$  and I get 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 6.0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1/3 & 5/3\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: **Hint:** Start by subtracting $1/3$ Row 3 from Row 2 as the new Row 2. Next do a similar thing with Row 2 to  Row 1 as the new Row 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrices are row equivalent so far and you have obtained a row echelon form.

To obtain the reduced row echlon form.

Perform 
$$R_2-\frac13R_3, R_1-R_3, R_1-R_2$$

Remark:

I use the convention of $R_i+cR_j$ to mean add $c$ times $R_j$ to $R_i$ and update $R_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is correct:
$$-2R_1+R_2 \Rightarrow R_2.$$
Your second step should be:
$$-R_1+R_3 \Rightarrow R_3.$$
Your third step should be:
$$\frac{1}{6}R_2 \Rightarrow R_2$$
$$\frac{1}{6}R_3 \Rightarrow R_3.$$
The resulting form you wrote is correct. Next steps are:
$$-\frac{1}{3}R_3+R_2 \Rightarrow R_2$$
$$-R_3+R_1 \Rightarrow R_1$$
$$-R_2+R_1 \Rightarrow R_1.$$